# angularjs: Avoid data loss when the page is refresh in web socket.io

Tags: angularjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Is there a way to avoid data loss when the page is refresh or the user disconnect in the page using web socket io?

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8888,function(){
   console.log('server started');
});
   console.log('connected');

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
   console.log('user connected');

socket.on("disconnect", function(o) {
   console.log('user left');
});

var seatArray =[];
socket.on("didSelectSeat",function(data){
  io.sockets.emit("seatSelected",seatArray);
  seatArray.push(data);
      console.log(seatArray);


});
```

I tried the code above but when the user disconnect, the other data is loss. Is there a way to fix this. I pushed them inside the array but it not works still. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want robust data persistency you need some sort of storage, and I highly recommend something like Redis in combination with MongoDB. Storing stuff into an array will not be too much efficient.